# How reset ram by useing TI-Basic programming in TI-89 calculator

Tags: ti-basic

This is possible by manually pressing the F6 button and selecting Clear a-z...
How possible in the TI-Basic (TI-89) programming environment?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uYec.png)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to exempt your program from deletion?  Resetting RAM will delete even the program that you are creating.

Answer (score 0):

The DelVar statement deletes a variable. Of course, deleting `a`-`z` manually would be a pain. Instead, you can do:

```
delaz()
Prgm
Local ch,ind,var
ord("a")→ch
For ind,0,25
 char(ch+ind)→var
 DelVar #var
EndFor
EndPrgm
```

`ord("a")` gets the character code for "a", `char(c)` returns a string containing the the character with code `c`, and `#var` gives a refrence to the variable named by string `var`.

If you define this program, you can simply use `delaz()` to delete `a`-`z` programmatically. Be careful not to use one letter names for any of the local variables, because you will delete them before the program finishes.